# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.DataTable' to DataSets.General.StudentDataTable'

Tags: c#, .net, datatable, dataset

I have a dataset containing some datatables, now i want to fetch a datatable from db and add it to the existing datatable in dataset i am using below line

```
  return (DataSets.General.StudentDataTable) ds.Tables["DSDummy"];
```

But its giving me following error

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.DataTable' to
>   DataSets.General.StudentDataTable'. An explicit conversion exists

can someone please tell me how to cast this object? any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Is `ds.Tables["DSDummy"]` actually a strongly typed DataTable of type `DataSets.General.StudentDataTable`?

Comment: I wouldn't expect that line of code to produce that compile error. What's the return type of your method?

Comment: return type of my method is "DataSets.General.StudentDataTable", and DSDummy is a strongly typed datatable. it doesn't give any compile time error but gives an exception like 'Unable to cast etc etc etc'

Comment: ds.Tables["DSDummy"] is strongly typed DataSets.General.StudentDataTable?  Not just happened to have the same type definition?  What do you mean fetch a datatable from db?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `ds` is a strongly typed dataset, I would expect it to have an explicit property for the DSDummy table, something like `ds.DSDummy`, rather than going through the `Tables` collection, which bypasses the strong typing.

However, even as it stands, the explicit cast *should* have worked. Is it possible that you have `DataSets.General.StudentDataTable` defined more than once - once manually and once automatically from the DataSet Generator - and it's conflicting?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aeskbwf7.aspx)

Below code was taken from the above link.

```
DataSet customerOrders = new DataSet("CustomerOrders");

DataTable ordersTable = customerOrders.Tables.Add("Orders");

DataColumn pkOrderID =
ordersTable.Columns.Add("OrderID", typeof(Int32));
ordersTable.Columns.Add("OrderQuantity", typeof(Int32));
ordersTable.Columns.Add("CompanyName", typeof(string));

ordersTable.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { pkOrderID };
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to load one `DataTable` into another one, you can use the [DataTable.Merge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk68ew7b.aspx) method:

```
DataSets.General.StudentDataTable.Merge(ds.Tables["DSDummy"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like below... may be it help you...

**If you want to return dataset and assign to a Dataset then follow the below method..**

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds = GetData();

public dataset Sample GetData()
{
......
.......

return ds
}
```

**If you want to return Datatable and assign that to Dataset then follow the below method.**

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.Tables.Add(GetData());


public datatable Sample GetData()
{
......
.......

return ds.Tables["DSDummy"];
}
```

Comment: @Down voted Person : Can you give me the reason of downVoted...?

Comment: Well, not only do you not answer the question, your code samples aremostly filler, containing basically the code that is in the OP.